# why I can't show arabic language on HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website and this is the meta in the head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but all arabic text shows like in the picture..

[image: Unicode problem]

but when I change the browser unicode to arabic it shows correctly, but I have to to it every refresh so it is not a solution at all.

Comment: Those question marks are a sign of invalid characters. You need to make sure the content you paste into the page is UTF-8 as well.

Comment: I'm storing those texts in php variables like this: $name = 'محمد';

Comment: Can you send a DEMO? Thanks! :P

Comment: Are you sure that your file is too in UTF-8? Check it plz!

Comment: Your PHP files are not encoded in UTF-8. Save them in UTF-8.

Comment: oh how stupid this is, saving the file in utf-8 is the last in my mind, and the funny thing is... this was the problem... thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For solve that problem,** You only have to save all your PHP files in UTF-8 too...

Check that!  :P

**A only meta charset in UTf-8 doesn't works... Rembember it forever :P** It happens to me every time.. :P

**If you use Sublime Text,** you can save it like that:

[image: Save with UTf-8 Encoding]

**if you not,** I recommend you you to use sublime text: http://www.sublimetext.com/
it will give you some life years.. xD

Comment: thanks very much but you solved it too early, I need 9 minutes to choose it as correct answer :)